# Need logo to to be large enough so that it won't be pixelated when blown up for video on large screen

Tags: logo, png

I have created a logo in Illustrator and need to use it in our video. Our clients will be playing on a large  screen and want to make sure the file is large enough so when blown up it will not be pixelated. I saved logo to png for transparent background.

We looked at our clients logo and their dimensions are 7500x2785

The logo I created and saved as png is only 563x272

Both my logo and clients logo are simple text logos and aren't that different

Do I need to adjust something so my logo will not be pixelated when video is played on a large screen?

Comment: What size is the screen, in pixels?

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions in pixels has no sense if you do not define the real proportional size.

What you need to define is exactly what TV is going to display it.

- Full HD? (1920x1080)
- 4K? (3840×2160)
- Any special resolution like 1366x768, 1440x1080, 1280x720 or DCI variations?

And make a canvas of exactly that dimension. Then place the logo of the porportional size relative to the canvas. If you export the full canvas it will meet that dimesnion.

For example a logo that is half the screen on a FullHD Screen:
[image]

Versus the same proportion on a 4k screen:
[image]
I asume the transparent png is meant to be superimposed on an aditional video. As long as that other process does not re escale it that file of the final resolution with a transparent background will do fine.

A generic file could be preparing it at 8k resolution (7680×4320 and send it so the other process just downsample it if needed)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pixel dimensions do not matter for display size when using Vector Graphics.

The beauty of vector graphics is they remain sharp at any size. It has to do with being defined with mathematical formulas rather than a pixel grid of fixed size.

So, to make a logo that will display nicely at any size, save it in  a vector format. You are right to use a .Png. (this is only true with simple flat shapes and text, like you described yours as being).

A .PNG 24 with transparent background at 500 pixels should do the trick.

Use the "Save for Web" or new version its under "Export"

Make it, save it, blow it up so it fills your screen and check if the resolution is satisfactory, and if so then you're done. If not, if there is blur, jaggies or aliasing then go back into original .AI file, look it over for any defects, remove shadows, blur, edge effects or anything which doesn't look crisp, and save out as a .PNG again.

It wouldn't hurt to outline type and flatten everything before saving.

There are some tricks to make your logo visible as the video plays under it. All light or all dark will disappear when the underlying video is light or dark. I recommend contrasting thick outlines or bright mid range colors like yellow or orange.

The answer above does raise important issues of proportion, making sure your logo stays the right shape on different screen sizes. I believe after effects can apply graphics that will not distort any  more than the video itself, but it's something you'll have to look into.

I've seen some questions/answers on here discussing making many versions of a logo for different screen ratios and pixel density.

Answer (score 0):

- I'd open a new Photoshop document 7000x2785px...
- copy the logo from Illustrator
- paste into Photoshop as a Smart Object
- enlarge Logo to fit document
- save as PNG.

Unless your Illustrator file contains raster elements, this should work best.

Depending upon the actual logo design, you may need to provide this large size, as well as some smaller varying sizes if elements don't scale well themselves. It's often necessary to "tweak" or "adjust" an actual logo based upon usage. This is really all you can do for pixel-based files. If the client could use the vector file, they could resize as needed on their own.